# SOQL returns empty list for Quote

Tags: apex, soql

in SalesForce I have existing Quote record that has Approved status and all required fields are filled. Quote also has Quote Lines, and the calculations were done correctly.

Unfortunately when I try to fetch this record in Apex or Query Editor, I never receive it. In Developer Console in Query Editor window I try to execute:

`SELECT Id FROM Quote`

but the result is always empty.

When I query for objects like Account, OpportunityLineItem or Lead the data is returned correctly. The problem occurs specifically for Quote and QuoteLineItem.

I have been looking through the documentation, but couldn't find any solutions.
Do you have any idea what could cause the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are the sharing settings for those objects? Account is probably public read. Is the quote private, by any chance? If it is, and you don't own any of them with the user you are running the queries with, then you won't retrieve them due to lack of access.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira From what I see in 'Sharing Settings' the 'Quote' has 'Controlled by Parent' on both 'Default Internal Access' and 'Default External Access'. Parent in this case would be 'Opportunity'(correct me if I'm wrong) and it has 'Public Read Only/Private' settings.

Comment: Indeed, the Opportunity object is the parent of quotes. The query you tried to execute is pretty broad (no filters). What happens if you try to specify some filters or limits to the query on quotes (such as filtering by account or opportunity).

Comment: @RenatoOliveira I've done that intentionally to check if there are any object available. Previously I was querying with `WHERE OpportunityId = :opportunity.Id` but the result was still the same.

Comment: Are you querying via System Administrator profile? If not which profile do you have? I just created a dummy Quote and able to query no problem

Comment: I've checked in 'Manage Users->Users' and my user is has 'System Administrator' profile.

Comment: Did you find any answer ?